# Is there a helper method to extract origin host from request (to build a link)

Tags: spring-webflux

I receive request via a router :

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction() {
    return nest(path(API_PATH), route(GET("/"), indexHandler::getIndex));
}
```

handle by a method :

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getIndex(ServerRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

I need to extract the url use to request the service, I have different cases, sometimes request are direct to service, sometimes request go through proxy (and add X-Forwarded-Path,X-Forwarded-Path headers).

Is there a helper method, to extract this details from ServerRequest object ?